# I'd like to step down as a mod

Tags: support

I would like to step down as a mod.
I was not entirely sure how to proceed, so I posted here.
So if this is the wrong way - let me know and I'll go about it another way.

The reason why I do want to step down is because I do not feel I have the time and drive to be a proper mod like the site should have.
I'm very busy with work, and family life is taking up the rest.

So I feel it's better to leave it to someone else that can fill the shoes better then what I'm capable of now.

Answer (score 2):

Message received! There's no super formal process here; a meta post is maybe a little unconventional but totally fine. We'll be in touch to work out the details soon. Thank you for your time spent as mod!

Answer (score 2):

thanks for all your work. In general I guess it would be good to join the [Teachers' Lounge chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/4/teachers-lounge). There are community mods who can help or there is also a mail address for those issues.