# New moderator wanted on Tor SE

Tags: discussion, moderators

A couple years ago, we on the Community Team [made our guidelines for graduation and site closure a bit more concrete](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites) than they had been in the past. Here's the most relevant bit:

> If there's enough moderation for a public beta site to consistently remain free of spam, for flags to be cleared, and for our Be Nice policy to be upheld, your site will remain open. However, if ... we can’t find any suitable volunteers to step forward, the site gets closed.

Right now, having enough moderation is **not** a problem on this site. However, as some of you may have already seen, [one of your current moderators would like to step down](https://tor.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339/id-like-to-step-down-as-a-mod). If you're interested in being a replacement, please let me or another Community Manager know. `pops@(either stackoverflow or stackexchange).com` works, as does replying to this post.

Comment: Are you saying that if we don't have an additional moderator, the site will be closed (despite there being enough moderation)?  That's how I'm reading the quoted text, but I want to make sure I'm interpreting that correctly.

Comment: Not in the short term. Even if there's only one moderator, we'll keep the site open as long as the site is running okay. We really prefer to have three, though. That way, people can leave the site for a day or two, or go on vacation, without feeling guilty, and there are others to confer with if a tricky situation comes up. In the long term, well, nothing lasts forever. People get married, give birth, change jobs, and have all kinds of other life events happen that take them away from moderating.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  If there was (or is) an urgent need, I'd volunteer (I have some moderator-type privileges on other SEs, and moderator experience other places on the internet), but otherwise I think it'd be much better to have someone who's more active on this SE than I am.

Answer (score 3):

I'm the mod that wanted to step down. Things have now changed since then, so now I feel I have time to resume moderating, so I'm resuming where I left off.